# Sum of holomorphic squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis

Consider a variable $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and assume $u(z) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $H(z) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Further assume that $H(z)$ is symmetric positive definite for every $z$. Consider the function

$$
f(z) = u^T(z)H(z)u(z).
$$

If you diagonalize $H(z)$ then you can write $f(z)$ as a sum of squares.

Assume $u(z)$ and $H(z)$ are holomorphic. Under what condition is it possible to write:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^p g_k^2(z),
$$
where each $g_k(z)$ is holomorphic?

I'm aware that if the eigenvalues of $H(z)$ are distinct, then something can be done. I want to know if there's anything better than that? In my case, $0$ can be an eigenvalue of multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: For any real analytic function $f(x)\ge 0$, its positive square root is also real analytic (since the zeros are of even order, and there are no problems at other points), so that works without any assumptions. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?)

Comment: OK yes that's what I need. Can't accept your answer though, it's in a comment.

Comment: Hm does that work in multiple variables?

Comment: Also, the positive square root of $x^2$ is $|x|$ so there's a glitch?

Comment: Indeed, "positive square root" was nonsense, but the basic claim is true: near a zero an $f\ge 0$ looks like $(x-a)^{2n}g(x)$, $g(a)\not=0$, and $(x-a)^n \sqrt{g(x)}$ works fine as a holomorphic square root locally. On the intervals where $f>0$ there is no problem (either positive or negative square root works), and then we patch these together as required by what happens at the zeros.

Comment: If the rank of $H(z)$ is constant (equivalently, the dimension of the kernel is constant) then I think you are still fine, but maybe that's too restrictive for you. In the general case, forgetting where $f(z)$ came from, it might possible when you relax the $g_k(z)$ to be meromorphic with singularities only where $H(z)$ drops rank. This is related to Hilbert's 17th problem for real analytic functions (see Ch.4 in this [recent survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.12595) for what's probably the state of the art).

Comment: I see. This might be a hard problem.

Comment: You are talking for one dimension; there are polynomials in two variables with degree 6 which are non-negative on $\mathbb R^2$ and not sum of squares of polynomials (same thing in three dimensions, degree 4).

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer my own question, as Igor Khavkine points out, it may be too hard. For the paper I'm writing, I was able to find a suitable "square root" to my analytic function. This is what I'm providing here, in case anyone else needs it. Recall that a unit is a nonzero holomorphic function. Also recall that a Weierstrass polynomial of degree $m$ is a function of the form
$$p(x,y) = x^m + \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a_j(y)x^j,$$
where $x \in \mathbb{C}$ and each $a_j(y)$ is holomorphic in $y$.

**Theorem.** *Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain, and let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on $U$. Let $K \subset U \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact in $U$. Write $z = (x,y)$ with $x \in \mathbb{C}$. Assume that, if $z \in \mathbb{R}^n \cap U$ then $f(z) \geq 0$. For every $z_0 \in K$ there is a neighborhood $B$ of $z_0$ and a Weierstrass polynomial $p(z)$ and a unit $u(z)$ on $U$ such that $f(x,y) = p(x,y)\;\overline{p(\bar{x},y}\,) \; u^2(x,y)$ on $B$.*

**Proof.**
By the Weierstrass preparation theorem, $f = qv$ on a neighborhood $B$ of $z_0$, where $q$ is a Weierstrass polynomial, and $v$ is a unit. Since $v$ is a unit, shrinking $B$ if necessary, the range of $v$ lies in some half-space that excludes the origin, and then $u = \sqrt{v}$ is holomorphic on $B$. Furthermore, one looks up in a book the form of the Weierstrass polynomial, to find that it is given by
$$
q(x,y) = \prod_{j=1}^m (x-\alpha_j(y)),
$$
where the $\alpha_j$ are roots of $x \to f(x,y)$ on $B$. Because $f \geq 0$, the coefficients of the Taylor series are all real, and the complex roots must occur in conjugate pairs, and also the real roots must have even multiplicities. Thus we may rewrite
$$
q(x,y) = 
\prod_{j=1}^{m/2} (x-\beta_j(y))(x-\bar{\beta}_j(y))
,
$$
e.g with $\Im \beta_j \geq 0$. Finally, put
$$
p(x,y) = \prod_{j=1}^{m/2} (x-\beta_j(y)).
$$